# Magento 2: my_variable is not defined in ArraySerialized

Tags: magento2, configuration, array, undefined-variable

I'm trying to make a custom store configuration with **ArraySerialized**
But at first, i try with 2 column and it working fine, i've successfully in created and get data from it, but then, i created 1 more column, and this issue show up
[image]

I've searched a lot but still no luck, please help
Here's what i done:

> etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="gssi_career" translate="label" sortOrder="150" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Careers</label>
            <tab>gssi</tab>
            <resource>Gssi_Contact::contact_config</resource>

            <group id="gssi_career_group" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Career Subject</label>
                <field id="gssi_career_field" translate="label" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>List Careers</label>
                    <frontend_model>Gssi\Career\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Fields</frontend_model>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
                </field>
            </group>

        </section>

    </system>
</config>
```

> Gssi\Career\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\Fields

```
<?php   
namespace Gssi\Career\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

/**
 * Class Active
 *
 * @package Gssi\Contact\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
 */
class Fields extends AbstractFieldArray {

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_addAfter = TRUE;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $_addButtonLabel;

    /**
     * Construct
     */
    protected function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare to render the columns
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender() {
        $this->addColumn('subject_code', ['label' => __('Subject Code')]);
        $this->addColumn('subject_label', ['label' => __('Subject Label')]);
        $this->addColumn('subject_email', ['label' => __('Subject Email')]);
        $this->_addAfter       = FALSE;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple....Remove your config entry in core_config_data. Try adding all columns at a time in protected function _prepareToRender() and run upgrade, compile and flush commands